# How to run two functions simultaneously in c++ winform?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, opencv

I am using opencv in a c++ winform and i want to show my webcam on two different picture box using threads.The problem is when one thread starts the other one is not running so one of the picture boxes show the webcam live but the other one is a static picture of it.I guess the problem can get solved if i can run the two threads start function at the same time but i dont know how to do it or the problem is just something else.Does anyone know how to show live webcam on these two different picture boxes using threads?
Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Here is the code down below

```
void start_picture_Box1()
{
    s1 = true;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    while (s1) {
        cap >> _frame1;

        mat2picture bimapconvert;
        this->pictureBox1->Image = bimapconvert.Mat2Bimap(_frame1);

        pictureBox1->Refresh();
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void start_picture_Box2()
{
    s2 = true;
    VideoCapture cap1(0);
    while (s2) {
        cap1 >> _frame2;

        mat2picture bimapconvert;
        this->pictureBox2->Image = bimapconvert.Mat2Bimap(_frame2);

        pictureBox2->Refresh();
        if (waitKey(1) == 27) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public: void picture_Box1()

{
    pictureBox1->Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::start_picture_Box1));
}

 public: void picture_Box2()
 {
     pictureBox2->Invoke(gcnew System::Action(this, &MyForm::start_picture_Box2));
 }


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod1 = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::picture_Box1);
ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod2 = gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyForm::picture_Box2);
Thread^ MyThread1 = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod1);
Thread^ MyThread2 = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod2);

MyThread1->Start();
MyThread2->Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you `Invoke()` two picture-box updates, which means both are executing synchronously within UI thread. If you need to queue up, use `BeginInvoke()`. But, note that both `start_picture_Box1()` and `start_picture_Box2` will be running in the UI thread context.

You can update UI only from the main thread, so the only parallelism that you can get is in bitmap rendering. You have to separate the rendering logic and keep that part only in the thread functions, UI update should be in UI thread. Also, if you are sharing data between UI and rendering thread, ensure proper thread synchronization is in place.

Comment: so if the functions are getting called at the same time why is one picturebox showing the live webcam while the other one is just a static picture of it.I wnat them both to show live webcams how do i solve that?